# AspectRatio on ListLinePlot only considering ticks and not values

Tags: plotting

I want to plot some data in a ListLinePlot where the x- and y-values differ by at least 2 orders of magnitude. In this plot the x- and y- axis should not be scaled differently. This is the result that I achieved with the `AspectRatio` option:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 100}, {1, 110}, {2, 120}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

I thought `AspectRatio->1` will scale the x- and the y-axis in the same way, but instead only the distance between the ticks is the same. For example the x-axis value 0.4 and the y-axis value 20 have the same distance from the origin (both have 4 ticks).

I could fix this problem with specifiying `PlotRange -> {{0, 120}, {0, 120}}`, but I wonder if there is way to achieve the desired result without specifiying the plot range?

Comment: I find it a  strange  choice but `AspectRatio->Automatic` does what you need.

Comment: As @Kuba points out, `AspectRatio->Automatic` will use the same scale on both axes; however, you will need to change the `AxesOrigin` and `ImageSize` to get a useful result. For example, `ListLinePlot[{{0, 100}, {1, 110}, {2, 120}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 100}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 100]`